# Converting JSON yyyy-mm-ddthh:mm:ssz string to readable format in Swift?

Tags: swift, date-format

I'm trying to convert a string passed into my app as a string in the format in the question (yyyy-mm-ddthh:mm:ssz) to something that's comprehensible to the user. I tried creating a variable to do the date formatting:

```
var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
    return formatter
}
```

and then I tried to use it as follows:

```
Text("\(self.dateFormatter.date(from: self.dateToConvert))")
```

where 'dateToConvert' is the JSON string being passed around. The error I got was "Instance method 'appendInterpolation' requires that 'Date?' conform to '_FormatSpecifiable'". Any idea how to do this properly?

Comment: Don't put the `Z` in your date format in single quotes. The Z is intended to tell the date formatter to parse a time zone as part of the date.

Comment: A `SwiftUI.Text` expects that you give it the value (as a `Date`)  and formatter seperately. It'll format the date itself. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-format-text-inside-text-views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set some user friendly date format for your formatter. Then convert your `Date` object back to `String`:

```
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyyMMdd")
let text = dateFormatter.string(from: convertedDate)
```

And the use it in `Text` directly:

```
Text(text)
```

---

**EDIT**

Here is a simple demo how you can parse and display a `Date`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var date: Date? = Date()

    // by making `it static let` it is only computed once
    static let inputDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" // <- do not escape `Z` (time zone)
        return formatter
    }()

    static let outputDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
        return formatter
    }()

    // handling of optional `Date`
    var formattedDate: String {
        guard let date = date else { return "Date is nil" }
        return Self.outputDateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(formattedDate)
            .onAppear(perform: parseDate)
    }

    func parseDate() {
        let dateStr = // your date as `String`
        if let date = Self.inputDateFormatter.date(from: dateStr) {
            self.date = date
        } else {
            print("invalid date")
        }
        // alternatively if you don't care about errors:
        // date = Self.dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should never use a fixed dateFormat when displaying a date to the user. Btw no need to add spaces between the components in your template when localizing the dateFormat

Comment: Another issue is that OP is ignoring the timezone from the date string escaping the Z

Comment: And don't forget to set the locale to "en_US_POSIX" before setting a fixed dateFormat

Comment: @pawello2222 I tried using this solution and on the line where I set the text constant, I get "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Date'" as an error

Comment: @nickcoding I assumed `convertedDate` is the date you've already converted from your JSON. So it should be a `Date` object.

Comment: @pawello2222 I guess I'm just confused as to exactly how I should initialized the dateFormatter and then how I should display the date as Text() when I'm given some JSON string.

Comment: @nickcoding I updated my answer with a simple demo. Hope it helps.

Comment: outputDateFormatter doesn't make any sense. Why would you set the timezone to UTC and omit that info from the output string? It should display the current timezone. Btw You usually don't check an optional against nil and force unwrap it later in Swift. You should always properly unwrap optionals using `guard let` or `if let`

Comment: `guard let date = date else { return "Date is nil" }` and then `return Self.outputDateFormatter.string(from: date)` and setting the timezone in your `inputDateFormatter` is pointless if you wont use it to convert the date back to string.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, I removed time zone from the outputDateFormatter. And I decided to use one-liner in formattedDate because it was *shorter*. As you pointed out guard-let is *clearer*. I updated my answer. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The DateFormatter function `date(from:)` returns an `Optional` Date. If the string you provide is invalid, it will return nil.

Like with many things in Swift, you need to code to handle nil. One way to do that:

```
let dateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: self.dateToConvert) ?? "invalid"
print("Converted date = \(dateFromString)")
```

Alternately:

```
if let dateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: self.dateToConvert) {
    print("Converted date = \(dateFromString)")
} else {
    print("Date string is in an invalid format.")
}
```

Also note that when you log a `Date` it will be displayed in UTC, so the timezone will likely be different than your local timezone. If you want to display it in your local timezone you need to take extra steps.

Comment: OP is ignoring the timezone from the date string escaping the Z. This will result in a local time while the string is UTC time

Comment: This isn't working because self.dateToConvert is a date variable and "invalid" is a string. I think they both need to be dates